# Send error to Sentry without throwing in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sentry

I have a "ghost" express middleware, that is sometimes triggered to check stuff before a request gets answered. As it relies on some sort of reverse engineering, there's a high chance it encounters unhandled errors. I call it "ghost" precisely because it should NEVER end the request if it has an error.

Except I want these unhandled errors to be logged in Sentry, while at the same time passing the request to the next request handler. Is there any Sentry method that allows sending errors without throwing them?

For now, I simply log them with Winston at the "error" priority level, but I'm really trying to transition away from that with Sentry. Sentry contexts seem to be related with what I'm trying to do, but I didn't quite get what they are.

Answer (score 2):

My bad, should have read the docs more carefully. https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/enriching-events/context/#passing-context-directly